# Search suggestion in strings

Tags: java, search-suggestion

I have a text file containing:
`mariam amr sara john jessy salma mkkkkkaooooorllll`

the user enters a word to search for: for example: `maram`

As you can see, it does not exist in my text file .. I want to give suggestions, similar to the word maram is mariam

I used longest common subsequence but it gives `mariam` and `mkkkkkaooooorllll` because both contain the Longest common subsequence "mar"

I want to force the choice of mariam only
Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance

```
/**
 ** Java Program to implement Longest Common Subsequence Algorithm
 **/

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;

   /** Class  LongestCommonSubsequence **/
    public class  LongestCommonSubsequence
    {    
   /** function lcs **/
    public String lcs(String str1, String str2)
    {
    int l1 = str1.length();
    int l2 = str2.length();

    int[][] arr = new int[l1 + 1][l2 + 1];

    for (int i = l1 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for (int j = l2 - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            if (str1.charAt(i) == str2.charAt(j))
                arr[i][j] = arr[i + 1][j + 1] + 1;
            else 
                arr[i][j] = Math.max(arr[i + 1][j], arr[i][j + 1]);
        }
    }

    int i = 0, j = 0;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (i < l1 && j < l2) 
    {
        if (str1.charAt(i) == str2.charAt(j)) 
        {
            sb.append(str1.charAt(i));
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        else if (arr[i + 1][j] >= arr[i][j + 1]) 
            i++;
        else
            j++;
    }


    return sb.toString(); 
   //read text file, if a word contains sb.toString() , print it


}

/** Main Function **/
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{    
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Longest Common Subsequence Algorithm Test\n");

    System.out.println("\nEnter string 1");
    String str1 = br.readLine();

    System.out.println("\nEnter string 2");
    String str2 = br.readLine();

    LongestCommonSubsequence obj = new LongestCommonSubsequence(); 
    String result = obj.lcs(str1, str2);

    System.out.println("\nLongest Common Subsequence : "+ result);
}
```

}

Comment: I think thats because only `mariam` and `mkkk.. `starts with an `m`. I bet your algoright checks char after char from the beggining. Please show us the code

Comment: @Toumach it's beacause both  have the longest common subsequence mar and i will add the code

Comment: I cant answer but i will upvote so ppl will see

Answer (score 5):

There are a few techniques for fuzzy matching like this - Apache Commons provides some excellent tools for comparing how similar two strings are to one another. Check out the javadoc for [Levenshtein Distance](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#getLevenshteinDistance(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) and [Jaro Winkler Distance](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#getJaroWinklerDistance(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) calculation methods.

With Levenshtein Distance, the lower the score, the more similar the strings are:

```
StringUtils.getLevenshteinDistance("frog", "fog") == 1
StringUtils.getLevenshteinDistance("fly", "ant") == 3
```

You could also consider calculating the [Double Metaphone](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/language/DoubleMetaphone.html) for each string - this will allow you to determine how similar the strings 'sound' when spoken, even if they aren't necessarily spelt similarly.

Back to your question - using these tools, you could throw up suggestions if the user's search term is within a certain threshold of any of the strings in your text file.